# Vue.js: When rendering vue on a page inside a frame, the style tag is ignored

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to render vue on a page inside a frame(frame structure can not change)
Rendering succeeded, but there is a problem that styles are not applied

I wrote the sample code to reproduce below, can you tell me what is the problem?
[gitRepo](https://github.com/duyo-son/vue-frame-test)

### code

1. index.html
   Rendering vue inside a frame(#frm)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- not this one -->
    <div id="app"></div>
    <iframe src="framed.html" frameborder="1" width="50%" height="400px" id="frm"></iframe>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. main.ts
   Renders inside a Frame, but styles are not applied

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'


// bad (style tag not working)
let element = (document.getElementById('frm') as any)?.contentWindow.document.getElementById('app');
createApp(App).mount(element)


// good but I don't want to use this
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

3. App.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="css-test">
    show me red background
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
/** this is test css */
.css-test {
  background-color: red !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

### result

Styles are applied to vues that are rendered outside the frame, but styles are not applied to vues that are rendered inside the frame.
*vue rendering outside the frame is tested

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZPij.png)

could you please tell me what is the problem and how can I apply styles to vue inside a frame?

Comment: it is not Vue, it's the iframe problem. see this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: thanks I can fix this code. 

let frame = document.getElementById('frm') as any;
let element = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementById('app');
createApp(App).mount(element)

// solution
document.querySelectorAll('style').forEach((style) => {
    frame.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(style.cloneNode(true));
});

Answer (score 1):

Temporary solution:

```
let frame = document.getElementById('frm') as any;
let element = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementById('app');
createApp(App).mount(element)

// solution
document.querySelectorAll('style').forEach((style) => {
    frame.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(style.cloneNode(true));
});
```